# How to early break reduce() method?

Tags: javascript, loops, reduce

How can I break the iteration of `reduce()` method?

`for`:

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(Things[i] <= 0){
    break;
  }
};
```

`reduce()`

```
Things.reduce(function(memo, current){
  if(current <= 0){
    //break ???
    //return; <-- this will return undefined to memo, which is not what I want
  }
}, 0)
```

Comment: What is `current` in the code above? I don't see how these can do the same  thing. In any case there are methods that break early like `some`, `every`, `find`

Comment: `some` and `every` return booleans and `find` return a single record, what I want is to run operations to generate a memo. `current` is the currentValue. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: I mean what is `current` in the first piece of code?

Comment: The answer is you cannot break early from `reduce` , you'll have to find another way with builtin functions that exit early or create your own helper, or use lodash or something. Can you post a full example of what you want to do?

Comment: nothing special @elclanrs, just out of curiosity if it was possible to do that knowing that reduce is a case of iteration.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to do it. From the MDN definition of the `reduce` function: `The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value`. If you need something different than this, then you probably want to use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @Cristy—"*…from left to right…*" doesn't seem right, MDN needs fixing. *reduce* goes from lowest to highest index, which might be right to left, or top to bottom, or bottom to top, depending on your point of view. Of course there is *reduceRight*, but it's been influenced by more recent culture (*c.f. pop/push, shift/unshift* which don't infer any endian–ness).

Comment: @RobG You are right, but it says so because `Arrays` are instantiated like this: `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, where index `0` is at the left and the right most index is at the right. I don't see how you could look at this and not notice how `0` is left and `3` is right :)

Comment: @Cristy—sure, but array elements may be added in any sequence and may be moved around. Also, Arrays are just objects, so their properties only have a concept of order because of their index values, e.g. *for..in* **might** return the values in any order (IE used to return them in the order they were added). ;-)

Comment: In JS with higher order functions, one should avoid having such sinful thoughts at all costs. JS doesn't have a data type to represent a value alongside a failure possibility such as `Maybe Int` which may return ie `Just 10` or `Nothing`, or such as  `Either String Int` which may return `Left "Boom..!"` or `Right 10`. Short circuiting of higher order functions could only then be implemented properly if while folding you get a `Nothing` or `Left "quick result"`. This is available as `foldM` (monadic fold) in true functional languages like Haskell.

Comment: It's very simple. You don't break. You just stop mutating the state (i.e keep returning the accumulator that you're happy with).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You CAN break on any iteration of a .reduce() invocation by mutating the 4th argument of the reduce function: "array". No need for a custom reduce function. See [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for full list of `.reduce()` parameters.

*Array.prototype.reduce((acc, curr, i, array))*

The 4th argument is the *array* being iterated over.

```js
const array = ['apple', '-pen', '-pineapple', '-pen'];
const x = array
.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
    if(i === 2) arr.splice(1);  // eject early
    return acc += curr;
  }, '');
console.log('x: ', x);  // x:  apple-pen-pineapple
```

*WHY?:*

The one and only reason I can think of to use this instead of the many other solutions presented is if you want to maintain a functional programming methodology to your algorithm, and you want the most declarative approach possible to accomplish that. If your entire goal is to literally REDUCE an array to an alternate non-falsey primitive (string, number, boolean, Symbol) then I would argue this IS in fact, the best approach.

*WHY NOT?*

There's a whole list of arguments to make for NOT mutating function parameters as it's a bad practice.

---

**UPDATE**

Some of the commentators make a good point that the original array is being mutated in order to break early inside the `.reduce()` logic.

Therefore, I've modified the answer **slightly** by adding a `.slice(0)` before calling a follow-on `.reduce()` step, yielding a copy of the original array.
*NOTE*: Similar ops that accomplish the same task are `slice()` (less explicit), and spread operator `[...array]` ([slightly less performant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793076/6406690)). Bear in mind, all of these add an additional constant factor of linear time to the overall runtime `... + O(n)`.

The copy, serves to preserve the original array from the eventual mutation that causes ejection from iteration.

```js
const array = ['apple', '-pen', '-pineapple', '-pen'];
const x = array
    .slice(0)                         // create copy of "array" for iterating
    .reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
       if (i === 2) arr.splice(1);    // eject early by mutating iterated copy
       return (acc += curr);
    }, '');

console.log("x: ", x, "\noriginal Arr: ", array);
// x:  apple-pen-pineapple
// original Arr:  ['apple', '-pen', '-pineapple', '-pen']
```

Comment: This is really BAD ADVICE, because `splice` performs a visible mutation (`array`). According to the functional paradigm you'd use either a reduce in continuation passing style or utilize lazy evaluation with a right-associative reduce. Or, as a simpler alternative, just plain recursion.

Comment: **Hold On!** *by mutating the 4th argument of the reduce function: "array"* is not a correct statement. In this case it is happening (the example in the answer) because its cutting the array to single length array (first element) while its already reached index **2**, obviously next time, for index **3** it will not get a item to iterate (as you are mutating the original reference to array of length **1**). In case you perform a pop that will also mutate the source array too but not stop in between (if you are not at the second last index).

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee My statement is correct for my implicit meaning. It is not correct for your explicit meaning.  You should offer a suggestion on modifying the statement to include your points and I'll make the edit as it would improve the overall answer.

Comment: This is BAD! Like many others have said, it will mutate your source object.  If you're application is built on immutability which pretty much all are these days then you're opening yourself up to disaster.

Comment: @TheNickyYo Hence the part titled "Why Not?".

Comment: I prefer reaching for the spread operator to avoid any unwanted mutations, [...array].reduce()

Comment: @eballeste Yup, totally works. Interesting benchmarks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793076/6406690) comparing the two.

Comment: Yep @eballeste, and that one simple step makes this solution fantastic

Comment: It would be unwise to use mutation to short circuit a reduction.  Write a custom reduce function which allows for early breaking.  Don't shoehorn the native into doing something it wasn't designed for.

Comment: @Mario I would argue using a custom reduce function is a shoehorn. A shoehorn is an outside instrument used to assist you putting on your shoes. A short-circuit is utilizing no outside instrument to assist you, but rather working creatively within the confines of the functional arguments you're natively given although often unused/ignored (4th arg; array). Using your example, this solution is more appropriately compared to pulling off one shoe using the toe of the partner shoe; something some parents frown upon but is quite expeditious and effective in ejecting my foot from my shoes.

Comment: @TobiahRex - I would never write a function which passes an object whose mutation (side effect!) produces a desired result.  The design of the function makes me cringe.  I'll use a better function even if I have to write it.

Comment: that should be this, if you want break in this loop

`arr.reduce((acc, item, index, arr) => {
  if (condition) acc += 1
  else arr.splice(index)
  return acc
})`

Answer (score 49):

Don't use reduce. Just iterate on the array with normal iterators (for, etc) and break out when your condition is met.

Comment: Yes, this answer could be improved by explaining WHY it's possibly not best practice to use functional programming if you need to break the loop. One would assume the OP is fully aware of basic iterators and maybe they just want to avoid polluting the scope, who knows.

Comment: (I encountered this answer during review) I'd argue that this answer have value and should be kept. Although the OP could be aware what he is doing in wanting to use `reduce`, others could find it helpful in searching for a solution to their problem (as indicated by the number of upvotes).

Answer (score 22):

You can use functions like *some* and *every* as long as you don't care about the return value. *every* breaks when the callback returns false, *some* when it returns true:

```
things.every(function(v, i, o) {
  // do stuff 
  if (timeToBreak) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}, thisArg);
```

#### Edit

A couple of comments that "this doesn't do what reduce does", which is true, but it can. Here's an example of using *every* in a similar manner to *reduce* that returns as soon as the break condition is reached.

```js
// Soruce data
let data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

// Multiple values up to 5 by 6, 
// create a new array and stop processing once 
// 5 is reached

let result = [];

data.every(a => a < 5? result.push(a*6) : false);

console.log(result);
```

This works because the return value from *push* is the length of the *result* array after the new element has been pushed, which will always be 1 or greater (hence true), otherwise it returns false and the loop stops.

Comment: But if he is trying to do `reduce` then by definition he **does** care about the return value.

Comment: @torazaburo—sure, but I don't see it being used in the OP and there are other ways of getting a result. ;-)

Comment: `const isKnownZone = KNOWN_ZONES.some((v) => curZone.substr(v.length) === v)` I could use reduce, but that wouldn't be as efficient. The way I'm thinking about it is some and every are boolean functions... some elements are true, every element is true, in the set

Comment: the purpose of using `reduce` 99& cant be met by `every`

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this with an async reducer function?

Answer (score 10):

There is no way, of course, to get the built-in version of `reduce` to exit prematurely.

But you can write your own version of reduce which uses a special token to identify when the loop should be broken.

```
var EXIT_REDUCE = {};

function reduce(a, f, result) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let val = f(result, a[i], i, a);
    if (val === EXIT_REDUCE) break;
    result = val;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Use it like this, to sum an array but exit when you hit 99:

```
reduce([1, 2, 99, 3], (a, b) => b === 99 ? EXIT_REDUCE : a + b, 0);

> 3
```

Comment: You can use [lazy evaluation or CPS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34976936/5536315) to achieve the desired behavior:

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is incorrect.  You can break, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 6):

Array.every can provide a very natural mechanism for breaking out of high order iteration.

```js
const product = function(array) {
    let accumulator = 1;
    array.every( factor => {
        accumulator *= factor;
        return !!factor;
    });
    return accumulator;
}
console.log(product([2,2,2,0,2,2]));
// 0
```

Comment: but how do you do this without mutation.

Answer (score 1):

You can break every code - and thus every build in iterator - by throwing an exception:

```
function breakReduceException(value) {
    this.value = value
}

try {
    Things.reduce(function(memo, current) {
        ...
        if (current <= 0) throw new breakReduceException(memo)
        ...
    }, 0)
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof breakReduceException) var memo = e.value
    else throw e
}
```

Comment: This is probably the least efficient execution-wise of all the answers. Try/catch breaks the existing execution context and falls back to the 'slow path' of execution. Say goodbye to any optimizations that V8 does under the covers.

Comment: Not extreme enough. How about this: `if (current <= 0) window.top.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use try...catch to exit the loop.

```js
try {
  Things.reduce(function(memo, current){
    if(current <= 0){
      throw 'exit loop'
      //break ???
      //return; <-- this will return undefined to memo, which is not what I want
    }
  }, 0)
} catch {
  // handle logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break from inside of a `reduce` method. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you could alter the final result (which is one reason you may want to do this)

```js
const result = [1, 1, 1].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // returns 3

console.log(result);
```

```js
const result = [1, 1, 1].reduce((a, b, c, d) => {
  if (c === 1 && b < 3) {
    return a + b + 1;
  } 
  return a + b;
}, 0); // now returns 4

console.log(result);
```

Keep in mind: you cannot reassign the array parameter directly

```js
const result = [1, 1, 1].reduce( (a, b, c, d) => {
  if (c === 0) {
    d = [1, 1, 2];
  } 
  return a + b;
}, 0); // still returns 3

console.log(result);
```

However (as pointed out below), you CAN affect the outcome by changing the array's contents:

```js
const result = [1, 1, 1].reduce( (a, b, c, d) => {
  if (c === 0) {
    d[2] = 100;
  } 
  return a + b;
}, 0); // now returns 102

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Re "*You cannot mutate the argument values directly in a way that affects subsequent computations*", that isn't true. ECMA-262 says: [*If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callbackfn will be the value at the time reduce visits them*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce). Your example doesn't work because you're assigning a new value to *d*, not modifying the original array. Replace `d = [1, 1, 2]` with `d[2] = 6` and see what happens. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As the `promise`s have `resolve` and `reject` callback arguments, I created the `reduce` workaround function with the `break` callback argument. It takes all the same arguments as native `reduce` method, except the first one is an array to work on (avoid monkey patching). The third [2] `initialValue` argument is optional. See the snippet below for the `function` reducer.

```js
var list = ["w","o","r","l","d"," ","p","i","e","r","o","g","i"];

var result = reducer(list,(total,current,index,arr,stop)=>{
  if(current === " ") stop(); //when called, the loop breaks
  return total + current;
},'hello ');

console.log(result); //hello world

function reducer(arr, callback, initial) {
  var hasInitial = arguments.length >= 3;
  var total = hasInitial ? initial : arr[0];
  var breakNow = false;
  for (var i = hasInitial ? 0 : 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = arr[i];
    var currentIndex = i;
    var newTotal = callback(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr, () => breakNow = true);
    if (breakNow) break;
    total = newTotal;
  }
  return total;
}
```

And here is the `reducer` as an Array `method` modified script:

```
Array.prototype.reducer = function(callback,initial){
  var hasInitial = arguments.length >= 2;
  var total = hasInitial ? initial : this[0];
  var breakNow = false;
  for (var i = hasInitial ? 0 : 1; i < this.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = this[i];
    var currentIndex = i;
    var newTotal = callback(total, currentValue, currentIndex, this, () => breakNow = true);
    if (breakNow) break;
    total = newTotal;
  }
  return total;
};

var list = ["w","o","r","l","d"," ","p","i","e","r","o","g","i"];

var result = list.reducer((total,current,index,arr,stop)=>{
  if(current === " ") stop(); //when called, the loop breaks
  return total + current;
},'hello ');


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce functional version with break can be implemented as 'transform', ex. in underscore.

I tried to implement it with a config flag to stop it so that the implementation reduce doesn't have to change the data structure that you are currently using.

```
const transform = (arr, reduce, init, config = {}) => {
  const result = arr.reduce((acc, item, i, arr) => {
    if (acc.found) return acc

    acc.value = reduce(config, acc.value, item, i, arr)

    if (config.stop) {
      acc.found = true
    }

    return acc
  }, { value: init, found: false })

  return result.value
}

module.exports = transform
```

Usage1, simple one

```
const a = [0, 1, 1, 3, 1]

console.log(transform(a, (config, acc, v) => {
  if (v === 3) { config.stop = true }
  if (v === 1) return ++acc
  return acc
}, 0))
```

Usage2, use config as internal variable

```
const pixes = Array(size).fill(0)
const pixProcessed = pixes.map((_, pixId) => {
  return transform(pics, (config, _, pic) => {
    if (pic[pixId] !== '2') config.stop = true 
    return pic[pixId]
  }, '0')
})
```

Usage3, capture config as external variable

```
const thrusts2 = permute([9, 8, 7, 6, 5]).map(signals => {
  const datas = new Array(5).fill(_data())
  const ps = new Array(5).fill(0)

  let thrust = 0, config
  do {

    config = {}
    thrust = transform(signals, (_config, acc, signal, i) => {
      const res = intcode(
        datas[i], signal,
        { once: true, i: ps[i], prev: acc }
      )

      if (res) {
        [ps[i], acc] = res 
      } else {
        _config.stop = true
      }

      return acc
    }, thrust, config)

  } while (!config.stop)

  return thrust
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing you do not need to return an array, perhaps you could use `some()`?

Use `some` instead which auto-breaks when you want. Send it a `this` accumulator. Your test and accumulate function **cannot be an arrow function** as their `this` is set when the arrow function is created.

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var accum = {accum: ''};
function testerAndAccumulator(curr, i, arr){
    this.tot += arr[i];
    return curr==='c';
};
accum.tot = "";
array.some(testerAndAccumulator, accum);

var result = accum.tot;
```

In my opinion this is the better solution to the accepted answer provided you do not need to return an array (eg in a chain of array operators), as you do not alter the original array and you do not need to make a copy of it which could be bad for large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

So, to terminate even earlier the idiom to use would be arr.splice(0).
Which prompts the question, why can't one just use arr = [] in this case?
I tried it and the reduce ignored the assignment, continuing on unchanged.
The reduce idiom appears to respond to forms such as splice but not forms such as the assignment operator??? - completely unintuitive - and has to be rote-learnt as precepts within the functional programming credo ...

```js
const array = ['9', '91', '95', '96', '99'];
const x = array
.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
    if(i === 2) arr.splice(1);  // eject early
    return acc += curr;
  }, '');
console.log('x: ', x);  // x:  99195
```

Comment: With `arr.splice()` you are affecting the current array. With assignment, that array still exists in memory untampered, you've only changed the reference of the var to a completely new array. Reduce wont care about the reference change because it has it's own references to the untampered array (`acc` and `curr` in your example).

Comment: @RandyHall `acc` and `curr` aren't references to the array - since `acc` is the return value, and `curr` is the current element. `arr` is a reference to the untampered array, though - of course internally it would be using `this` (or the engine's non-js equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that inside of the accumulator it is not possible to just stop the whole process. So by design something in the outer scope must be manipulated, which always leads to a necessary mutation.

As many others already mentioned `throw` with `try...catch` is not really an approach which can be called *"solution"*. It is more a hack with many unwanted side effects.

The only way to do this **WITHOUT ANY MUTATIONS** is by using a second compare function, which decides whether to continue or stop. To still avoid a `for`-loop, it has to be solved with a recursion.

The code:

```js
function reduceCompare(arr, cb, cmp, init) {
    return (function _(acc, i) {
        return i < arr.length && cmp(acc, arr[i], i, arr) === true ? _(cb(acc, arr[i], i, arr), i + 1) : acc;
    })(typeof init !== 'undefined' ? init : arr[0], 0);
}
```

This can be used like:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function join(acc, curr) {
    return acc + curr;
}

console.log(
    reduceCompare(
        arr,
        join,
        function(acc) { return acc.length < 1; },
        ''
    )
); // logs 'a'

console.log(
    reduceCompare(
        arr,
        join,
        function(acc, curr) { return curr !== 'c'; },
        ''
    )
); // logs 'ab'

console.log(
    reduceCompare(
        arr,
        join,
        function(acc, curr, i) { return i < 3; },
        ''
    )
); // logs 'abc'
```

I made an npm library out of this, also containing a TypeScript and ES6 version. Feel free to use it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-reduce-compare

or on GitHub:

https://github.com/StefanJelner/array-reduce-compare

Answer (score 0):

You could to write your own reduce method. Invoking it like this, so it follows same logic and you control your own escape / break solution. It retains functional style and allows breaking.

```js
const reduce = (arr, fn, accum) => {
  const len = arr.length;
  let result = null;
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i=i+1) {
    result = fn(accum, arr[i], i)
    if (accum.break === true) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return result
}

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'shouldnotgethere']
const myResult = reduce(arr, (accum, cur, ind) => {
  accum.result = accum.result + cur;
  if(ind === 2) {
    accum.break = true
  }
  return accum
}, {result:'', break: false}).result

console.log({myResult})
```

Or create your own reduce recursion method:

```js
const rcReduce = (arr, accum = '', ind = 0) => {
  const cur = arr.shift();
  accum += cur;
  const isBreak = ind > 1
  return arr.length && !isBreak ? rcReduce(arr, accum, ind + 1) : accum
}

const myResult = rcReduce(['a', 'b', 'c', 'shouldngethere'])
console.log({myResult})
```

Answer (score 0):

I find below way as the only elegant way to do it. Idea is to create a small function which simply returns passed thing. I call this function dumbReducer. and a wrapper function which decides whether to call dumbReducer or function which does some processing.

```
const dumbReducer = (acc, _value) => acc;
const reducer = (acc, value) => acc + value; // or whatever your processing is
const reducerWrapper = (acc, value) => {
  if(acc < 10) { return reducer(acc, value) } // Your condition
  return dumbReducer(acc, value)
};
things = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
things.reduce((acc, current_thing) => {
  return reducerWrapper(acc, current_thing);
}, 0) // Returns 10 i.e 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 without processing (or dumbly processing) 5,6
```

Works nice unless you have very high number of things to skip. In that case we are sort of wasting lot of cycles. I use this approach when things is actually a list of functions with matching signature to be applied on a starting value and there is a in between break away condition.

Answer (score -1):

Another simple implementation that I came with solving the same issue:

```
function reduce(array, reducer, first) {
  let result = first || array.shift()

  while (array.length > 0) {
    result = reducer(result, array.shift())
    if (result && result.reduced) {
      return result.reduced
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to chain promises sequentially with reduce using the pattern below:

```
return [1,2,3,4].reduce(function(promise,n,i,arr){
   return promise.then(function(){
       // this code is executed when the reduce loop is terminated,
       // so truncating arr here or in the call below does not works
       return somethingReturningAPromise(n);
   });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

But need to break according to something happening inside or outside a promise
things become a little bit more complicated because the reduce loop is terminated before the first promise is executed, making truncating the array in the promise callbacks useless, I ended up with this implementation:

```
function reduce(array, promise, fn, i) {
  i=i||0;
  return promise
  .then(function(){
    return fn(promise,array[i]);
  })
  .then(function(result){
    if (!promise.break && ++i<array.length) {
      return reduce(array,promise,fn,i);
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  })
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var promise=Promise.resolve();
reduce([1,2,3,4],promise,function(promise,val){
  return iter(promise, val);
}).catch(console.error);

function iter(promise, val) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (promise.break) return reject('break');
      console.log(val);
      if (val==3) {promise.break=true;}
      resolve(val);
    }, 4000-1000*val);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like follows, for example in the `some` method where short circuiting can save a lot:

```js
const someShort = (list, fn) => {
  let t;
  try {
    return list.reduce((acc, el) => {
      t = fn(el);
      console.log('found ?', el, t)
      if (t) {
        throw ''
      }
      return t
    }, false)
  } catch (e) {
    return t
  }
}

const someEven = someShort([1, 2, 3, 1, 5], el => el % 2 === 0)

console.log(someEven)
```

UPDATE

Away more generic answer could be  something like the following

```js
const escReduce = (arr, fn, init, exitFn) => {
    try {
      return arr.reduce((...args) => {
          if (exitFn && exitFn(...args)) {
              throw args[0]
          }
          return fn(...args)
        }, init)
    } catch(e){ return e }
}

escReduce(
  Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => i+1),
  (acc, e, i) => acc * e,
    1,
    acc => acc > 1E9 
); // 6227020800
```

give we pass an optional `exitFn` which decides to break or not