# short circuit Array.reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, short-circuiting

A toy example of a pattern I am trying to solve elegantly.  In the below algorithm, I would like to immediately return 0 from reduce when I find an element with a value of 0 without visiting the remaining elements.

```
let factors = [2,3,6,0,9,4,4,4];
function product(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => (acc * elem), 1);
}
```

Is there some way to break out of the reduce iteration?

Comment: write your custom reduce function if you have specific requirements.

Comment: reduce function in general would iterate over the entire array.

Comment: use break to end reduce

Comment: Why not just `return ~arr.indexOf(0) ? 0 : arr.reduce(/* ... */);`

Comment: @scniro, thanks, sorry, I didn't see that question.

Comment: @Emissary, that would work for the above example but not my application of this pattern.

Comment: You are right Xufux, just realized that right now. your answer is right here. you need to make your own reduce function. if you want to use it functionally 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144406/how-to-break-on-reduce-method

Answer (score -2):

You can short circuit reduce by mutating the original array.

```js
let factors = [2, 3, 6, 0, 9, 4, 4, 4];

function product(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, elem, i, array) => (array[i] === 0 ? (arr.length = i, elem) : (acc * elem)), 1);

}
console.log(product(factors))
```