# Why reduce is affected by floating point issue and for loop not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I write following code with reduce method, values are imprecise:

```
return bytes.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
                 return accumulator + (currentValue * Math.pow(256,(bytes.length - 2) - index));
    }
)
```

eg. output numbers `5.99609375, 10.99609375, 7.99609375, 14.99609375`
But when I write following code result is precise:

```
let result = 0.0;
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; ++i) {
                result = result + (bytes[i] * Math.pow(256, (bytes.length - 2) - i));
    }
return result
```

eg. output numbers `5, 10, 7, 14`
Input byte arrays are:

```
Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 5, 255]
Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 10, 255]
Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 7, 255]
Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 14, 255]
```

Why is that? Is there a way to make reduce method work precisely?

```js
const res = document.getElementById('result');
const res2 = document.getElementById('result2');
const arr = a = [
  [0, 0, 5, 255],
  [0, 0, 10, 255],
  [0, 0, 7, 255],
  [0, 0, 14, 255]
];
const fn = (bytes) => {
  let result = 0.0;
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; ++i) {
    result = result + (bytes[i] * Math.pow(256, (bytes.length - 2) - i));
  }
  return result
}
fn2 = (bytes) => {
  return bytes.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
    return accumulator + (currentValue * Math.pow(256, (bytes.length - 2) - index));
  })
}
res.innerText += `${arr.map(fn)}`;
res2.innerText += `${arr.map(fn2)}`;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Comment: both code snippets produce a single number and not several. Also, give a sample input to reproduce said behavior.

Comment: Riht, but these are eg. output numbers, not eg. output Arrays.

Comment: Also, please provide the bytes array.

Comment: You have not provided the initial value of the accumulator in the array#reduce.

Comment: I do not see the initial `0` accumulator in the call of Array#reduce(fx, accumulator)

Comment: The default is the first array element, i actually thought it was plain summation but that comment is the answer very likely.

Comment: Please provide real [mcve]s, preferably as [a live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Everything on stackoverflow must be upvoted - for properly formatted and solvable questions like this i don't get mad, unlike other questions for which i could write a bot to post within a day.

Comment: The two iteration methods are not equivalent, since the `for` loop misses the final element. If you change that, you will get the same result in both cases.

Comment: @vlaz You are right, but the question is why, and how to do same in reduce.

Comment: You cannot easily do it. This is because `reduce` is designed to run through the whole array - you could basically check if you've reached the last element and then exclude it but it might just be easier to just remove the last element before running `reduce` on the array. Something like `arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).reduce( /* ... */ )` can do it.

Comment: @vlaz in my case `bytes.slice(0.3).reduce...` was the answer. I see now also, it was wrong question, but it solved something, I spend too much time thinking, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why reduce is affected by floating point issue and for loop not? When I write following code with reduce method, values are imprecise

That is not a case of floating point issue. If you look at the results you will see something like this:

```
5.99609375
```

When you have floating point precision is something like this

```
0.020000000000000004
```

The problem is in the for loop because you're iterating only the first `n-1` items from **bytes** array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; ++i) {
```

Just iterate all the array items.

```
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
```

You are seeing two `values` because `reduce` method run through all the array items, and for loop run through first `n-1` items.

Unfortunately, there is no way, of course, to get the built-in version of **reduce** to exit prematurely.

But you can use `slice` method.

```
return bytes.slice(0, -1).reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
    return accumulator + (currentValue * Math.pow(256,(bytes.length - 2) - index));
})
```

Comment: Good answer but in for loop NOT in reduce I get expected output, so problem is not in for loop.

Comment: @Zydnar, you are getting a floating number because it's reached a step when you have `Math.pow(256, -1)` which is `1/256`. But in reduce method you cannot use `break` method or something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144406/how-to-break-on-reduce-method

Comment: You are seeing two values because `reduce` method run through all the array items, and `for` loop run through first `n-1` items.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

The for condition is wrong
Should be

```
 for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length ; ++i) {
```