# spread syntax vs slice method

Tags: javascript, slice, spread-syntax

I was trying to understand what is the difference between spread syntax vs slice method in the following approach.

suppose I want to make an actual copy of an array, I can probably easily do it using spread syntax

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Chips" , "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]
var newCitrus = [...fruits]
```

If I console.log this

```
["Banana", "Chips", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

but I can also create a copy of an array using the slice method. Considering the same array above, if I do something like this...

```
var citrus = fruits.slice(0);
```

and then console log it, it will give me exactly the same array which I would've got through spread syntax

```
["Banana", "Chips", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

Since both of them takes about the same time to code/write, What is the difference here? which approach should I usually choose?

Comment: `This will console.log` Huh? No, it won't. Why is that different from the `fruits`? Also, you're not using `splice` anywhere in your code

Comment: `slice` is absolutely not the same as `splice`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Ohh sorry my bad. Wrote that by accident.

Comment: As with many things in life there are often numerous ways to acheive same end result. Use what feels best. Without running perf tests this is primarily an opinion question

Comment: spread operator is about 5% **faster** than slice in Firefox - spread operator is about 60% **SLOWER** than slice in Chrome - so, you would use spread operator to convince people that Chrome is slower than Firefox

Comment: `slice` allows for more control which part of the array to take, whereas the spread operator allows for quick "pasting" into arrays, e.g. `["other", "elements", ...fruits]`.

Comment: @charlietfl in the above case, they both have absolutely no difference?

Comment: though, there's also `.concat` - which is about the same speed in firefox - and about 75% slower than spread ... so if you really want to slow chrome down, use concat

Comment: @Mark_M - so, not `[].concat([...arr].slice())`

Comment: @JaromandaX  check the first answer :)

Comment: @JaromandaX spread is _not an operator_, it is a _syntax_ ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - is that important? the URL for MDN documentation includes `Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax` ... so, you could argue it's a "spread syntax operator" - but in the end it doesn't even matter

Comment: @JaromandaX it actually is important. I've seen people ask things like "why can't I do `var args = ...arguments;`" and the answer is _because it's not an operator_.

Comment: fair enough @PatrickRoberts I didn't think of the implications of calling it an operator :p

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Performance aside `slice` is just a function on `Array.prototype` and `String.prototype` so it will work only for arrays and strings. Spread syntax on the other hand will work for any iterable (object which satisfy [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol)) so it will work out of the box on any `String`, `Array`, `TypedArray`, `Map` and `Set`. You can also easily [create custom iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#User-defined_iterables).

There is also a difference when it comes to `slice`ing and `spread`ing arrays with holes (sparse arrays). As you can see below, `slice` will preserve sparseness while `spread` will fill holes with `undefined`.

```
Array(3)         // produces sparse array: [empty × 3]
Array(3).slice() // produces [empty × 3]
[...Array(3)]    // produces [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Spread syntax can also be used to make shallow clones of objects:

```
const obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
const clone = { ...obj };
obj.foo === clone.foo // true
obj.baz === clone.baz // true
obj === clone         // false (references are different)
```

Answer (score 20):

[Measuring in Chrome](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2667/0/arrayprototypeslice-vs-spread-operator) shows that slice is far more performant than the spread operator, with 67M operations per second against 4M operations per second. If you're building for Chrome or an Electron app (which uses Chromium) I'd go for slice, especially for big data and real time applications.

[image: Measure results]

**EDIT:**

It seems like the Spread operator is now much faster, albeit still slower than Slice:

[image: Newer Measurement Results]

Comment: Ran your benchmark on current Chrome and having 75,333,251 ops/sec vs 68,604,739 ops/sec. Looks like spread operator improved a lot in current version

Comment: Spread Operator is faster in Firefox Safari, and Chrome Mobile IOS

Comment: Looks like spread is way faster https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2667/0/arrayprototypeslice-vs-spread-operator

Comment: @SergeyShteyn your benchmark slices `[ 1, 2 ]`. I don't think this is valid.

Comment: [1, 2] comparison replaced with correct one: https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/22387/0/arrayprototypeslice-vs-spread-operator-long-2

Comment: @SergeyShteyn not sure if you're not reading the results backwards (at least for me it shows slice being faster, just tried edge and firefox)

Comment: @VFDan just tried edge (chromium based) and firefox - edge had 40k/20k slice/spread, firefox had 30k/10k slice/spread, I guess chromium must have done some performance tuning since

Answer (score 7):

Performance will depend on the engine where its' running. And as with most Javscript code, it will probably be running in various different engines. So, use whatever feels aesthetically better. For me that's spread.

`...` is sheer beauty.

If you decide to go with slice, skip the 0, just say `.slice()`.

Answer (score 5):

Those two methods aren’t actually equivalent though. Slice is a function on `Array.prototype` and is aware of the array’s implementation. It will create a very efficient copy. More importantly though, `.slice()` will preserve the sparseness information of your array.

In contrast, `[...Array]` will simply create a new array from an iterable view of your existing array. Not necessarily as efficient.

Try this:

```
var a = [];
a.length = 3;
console.log("slice:", a.slice());
console.log("spread:", [...a]);
```

With Chrome Browser developer console, I get these results:

```
slice: (3) [empty × 3]
spread: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

If your array is particularly huge+sparse, `array.slice()` will be exceptionally fast. `[...array]` will probably hang your browser.

Comment: The slice() method returns a shallow copy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Thanks. I removed the word "deep", but it isn’t actually “shallow” either: “It returns a shallow copy *of elements* from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array” (emphasis mine).
I guess you could say it’s just a standard copy, as you would expect in any reference-based language: The array is new, the references in the array are unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

New versions of Chrome (72+) seem to have eliminated the performance gap.
https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ListResults/2667

Answer (score 0):

***Slice**:
The Slice method takes 2 arguments
1st Argument: Specifies from where the selection should be started.
For Example:*

```
let arr1 = [1,5,8,9];
arr1.slice(1); // [5,8,9]
```

From the first index (5) it will return the elements.

2nd Argument: Specifies at which level the endpoint should be. If you didn’t put this in the parenthesis while calling the slice method, it will return the elements from the starting index to the end of the array.

```
  let arr1 = [1,5,8,9];
console.log(arr1.slice(1,3));
    //[ 5, 8 ]
```

If you put a negative number while calling, the selection will be selected from the end of the array.

```
let arr1 = [1,5,8,9];
console.log(arr1.slice(-2));
//[ 8, 9 ]
```

**Spread Operator**:
I can use this Spread Syntax to solve this:

```
let arr1 = [1,3,6,7];
let arr3 = [5,...arr1,8,9];
console.log(arr3);
```