# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Recipe[]'. error in this line of code this: recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();

Tags: angular, typescript

Component code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-recipe-list',
    templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html'
})

export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes: Recipe[];
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
    }
}
```

Service:

```js
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class RecipeService { 
    recipeSelect = new EventEmitter();

    private recipes: Recipe[] = [
        new Recipe('A Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg'),
        new Recipe('Another Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg')];
    getRecipes() {
        this.recipes.slice();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should return this.recipes.slice() from getRecipes() method: `return this.recipes.slice();`

Comment: You forgot to add a `return` statement in your `getRecipes` method, so it's currently not returning anything, hence the error.

Comment: thank you . yes i had forgot to add return type

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the recipes from the `getRecipes` function

```
getRecipes(): Recipe[] {
    return this.recipes.slice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getRecipes(): Recipe[] {
    return [...this.recipes];
}
```

In your example, your service function does not return anything while you are expecting a collection back (this.items).

So you have to use the keyword return to achieve this.

Furthermore, you are using the [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to return a copy of your local collection, which is a good idea but for the sake of readability and potential performance, I prefer [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

See this discussion for the performance reasons : [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164161/spread-syntax-vs-slice-method)

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Code
getRecipes() {
         this.recipes.slice();
     }
```

Correct Code
getRecipes() {

```
         return this.recipes.slice();
     }
```