# How can I find an array element starting from the end of the array?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has array methods like `indexOf` and `find` for getting the first element in the array that matches the criteria. The counterpart to `indexOf` would be `lastIndexOf`, which searches starting from the end of the array instead. I'm wondering now if there is a counterpart to `find` that starts from the end of the array, like a native implementation of [Ramda's `findLast`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#findLast).

I would prefer to use neither `array.slice().reverse().find()` due to performance costs nor a `for` loop as it is verbose and not in the spirit of functional programming

Comment: How about find until not found and take previous

Comment: Do this help? https://medium.com/dailyjs/functional-js-with-es6-recursive-patterns-b7d0813ef9e3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight`, which is in the spirit of functional programming. However, it's not as easy ([but possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441371/6243352)) to return early upon finding a match as it is in a `for` loop:

```js
const lastIndexOf = (needle, haystack) => 
  haystack.reduceRight((a, e, i) => 
    a >= 0 ? a : e === needle ? i : -1
  , -1)
;

const arr = [1,4,3,5,5,4,5];
console.log(lastIndexOf(4, arr));
console.log(lastIndexOf(2, arr));
```

There's also recursion, which has similar efficiency problems (stack frame overhead, no instantaneous early return, having to write a helper or extra conditionals, you'll blow the stack if the array is large...):

```js
const lastIndexOf = (needle, haystack, idx) => 
  lastIndexOfHelper(needle, haystack, haystack.length - 1)
;

const lastIndexOfHelper = (needle, haystack, idx) => 
  idx < 0 || haystack[idx] === needle ? 
    idx : lastIndexOfHelper(needle, haystack, idx - 1)  
;

const arr = [1,4,3,5,5,4,5];
console.log(lastIndexOf(4, arr));
console.log(lastIndexOf(2, arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

No there is not, but you can polyfill it easily:

```
 Array.prototype.findLast = function(fn) {
  for(let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    if(fn( this[i], i, this )) return this[i];
  return null;
 };



console.log([5,4,3,2,1].findLast(el => el > 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Lodash has a _.findLastIndex() method which interates over a collection from right to left. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findLastIndex

Not sure as to its performance though

Comment: I'd expect Lodash's performance to be about as good as anything you might code yourself.