# why return statement doesn't stop the function execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
const arr = [5,1,3,2,6];
const output = arr.reduce(function (acc, curr){
    acc = acc + curr;
    return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(output);
```

since there is return statement there, why the reduce function keeps iterating as return statement ends any loop or function as per my knowledge.

Comment: The `return` is in the callback function. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#callbackfn) for how it is used

Comment: It does stop the function execution. However, that function is called (and stopped) five times. However, that `return` does not stop the execution of `reduce` itself, as it is not inside the body of `reduce`. See [How to early break reduce() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144406/how-to-early-break-reduce-method)

Comment: *"*return statement ends any loop*" - there is no loop in your code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. However, you should also remember that `Array.reduce` is a function, which is different from the function you pass to it.

When you call `Array.reduce` and pass in the function, it uses that function to do [something](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The return of the function does not also terminate `Array.reduce`, until `Array.reduce` itself does a `return` or exits after it has finished doing whatever it does.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function in JavaScript does not automatically stop its execution when a return statement is encountered. Instead, it iterates over each element of the array, applying the provided callback function to accumulate a single result. The return statement inside the callback function simply specifies the value to be used as the accumulator in the next iteration.

If you want to stop the execution consider using `break` inside the for loop and inside followed by an `if` condition.

Refer the below code for reference

```js
   

const arr = [5, 1, 3, 2, 6];
const condition = 10;
let output = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output += arr[i];

    if (output >= condition) {
        break; // exit the loop when the condition is met
    }
}

console.log(output);  // Output will be 9 (5 + 1 + 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

The **reduce()** method returns a single value: the function's accumulated result.